# Python nested for loop ordering

Tags: python, pandas, loops

i am having issues get a nested for loop to output individual csv files for an API call. The API call is paginated, so we have to query the API multiple times and append the data Also have to loop through for every exchange.

The way the code is now it's only outputting the last page of data for a couple of exchanges and the the following exchanges just have 'name' in the CSV, no other data...

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
cg = CoinGeckoAPI()

import pandas as pd
import time

##grab a list of all the exchangeslisted on CG
ex_list = cg.get_exchanges_list()

#normalise the json
df = pd.json_normalize(ex_list)

#output to csv
#df.to_csv('exchange_list.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)

#make a list with just one column
id_list =  df['id'].to_list()


def read_exchange_tickers():
    for x in id_list:
        for i in range(1,10):
            appended_data = []
            data =  cg.get_exchanges_tickers_by_id(x, page = str(i))
            appended_data.append(data)
            #time.sleep(10)
        
            #define path + filename        
            path = 'ticker_lists/'        
            filename = path + x + '_' + '.csv'
            appended_data = pd.json_normalize(appended_data, record_path=['tickers'], meta=['name'])  
            appended_data.to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
            time.sleep(10)
    
read_exchange_tickers()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should collect all data for each id and then save the data to file.

```
def read_exchange_tickers():
    for x in id_list:
        appended_data = []

        # collect all the data for current id
        for i in range(1,10):
            data =  cg.get_exchanges_tickers_by_id(x, page = str(i))
            appended_data.append(data)

        # save the data to csv           
        path = 'ticker_lists/'        
        filename = path + x + '_' + '.csv'
        appended_data = pd.json_normalize(appended_data, record_path=['tickers'], meta=['name'])  
        appended_data.to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
        time.sleep(10)
```